# Stretching text box for a question can cause part of it to be hidden

Tags: bug, status-declined

When I post a comment, I can stretch the input box, and it's superimposed on top of the stuff on the right side of the page:

[image: Stretched comment text entry box]

But when I post a question or an answer, stretching the input box causes it to appear *behind* the stuff on the right side of the page:

[image: Stretched question text entry box]

And if I'm not careful, the control to change the size of the box can be hidden behind something else, making it impossible to change the size again.  Can this be fixed, so all text entry boxes are displayed in front of any other items?

I'm using Firefox 7.0.1 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah.....so don't do that.

This is a *browser* feature, not a Stack Exchange one...many sites won't handle this correctly, including ours, but we don't explicitly disable the stretch since it is useful in other dimensions.

Comment: I'm not suggesting disabling the stretch.  I'm *guessing* that there's something about the comment text box that causes it to appear on top of other content, and something about the posting text box that doesn't, and that if it's a browser bug there might be some way to work around it by tweaking the Stack Exchange code.  Is my guess incorrect?